# How to get a single value from MongoDB using PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb

So I have the following code to get a document from a collection in my database:

```
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.hyqa4.mongodb.net/academic?retryWrites=true&w=majority');
$filter = ['username' => $uname];
$options = ['projection' => ['_id' => 0]];
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options); 
$cursor = $manager->executeQuery("academic.users", $query); 

foreach($cursor as $document) {
  print_r($document);
}
```

I'm able to successfully retrieve a document by searching for the username, so if $uname is "Jon",  I get the following output:

```
stdClass Object ( [username] => Jon [email] => Jon@mail.com [passwd] => pass123 )
```

However, what I want to do is just return a single value from the document, so if I wanted to get the value for email, it would return:

```
Jon@mail.com
```

...so then I could store that value as a variable.
How would I do this?

Comment: And dont store password in plain text. Apply some encryption

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Std class objects can be accessed via `->` operator. So you can user `$document->email` to access individual email.  Is this what you are looking for

```
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.hyqa4.mongodb.net/academic?retryWrites=true&w=majority');
$filter = ['username' => $uname];
$options = ['projection' => ['_id' => 0]];
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options); 
$cursor = $manager->executeQuery("academic.users", $query); 

foreach($cursor as $document) {
  print_r($document->email);
}
```